# Редактор - VSC Проблема с кодировкой, Вместо введенного слова на русском языке выводит знаки вопросов в ромбиках(при вводе на английском все хорошо)

Tags: python

```
data = input("Введите текст: ")

file = open('data/text.txt', 'w')

file.write(data)

file.close()
```